jQuery set tranform3d effect

Trying to create this mouse tracking effect - which causes a transform3d change on the block and contents - and also adds a flash light where the mouse is.
How would you write this in vanilla js so it's stable - I am not sure on the formula used to calculate these degree changes - as they seem to go min -8 to max 9 degrees.
https://jsfiddle.net/qzo3ck5m/46/


var myElement = $("#p1");

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, zPos, el) {
  console.log("test");
  el.style.transform = `translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(${xPos}deg) rotateY(${yPos}deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg)`;
}


myElement.mousemove(function(event) {
  console.log("mousemoveY---", event.clientX, event.clientY);

  let y = event.clientY;
  let x = event.clientX;

  var position = {
    top: myElement[0].offsetTop,
    left: myElement[0].offsetLeft
  };

  console.log("x", x);
  console.log("y", y);

  console.log("position", position);

  let degx = position.left - x;
  let degy = position.top - y;

  console.log("degx", degx);
  console.log("degy", degy);

  let fullDegrees = 8;

  setTranslate(-degx / 20, -degy / 20, 0, myElement[0]);
});


myElement.mouseleave(function() {
  console.log("mouseleave");
  setTranslate(0, 0, 0, myElement[0]);
});
.container {
  padding: 40px;
}

.blockwrapper {
  will-change: transform;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);
  margin: 10px;
}

.block {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

.moved {
  background-color: pink;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="blockwrapper">
    <div class="block moved">Moved</div>
  </div>
  <div id="p1" class="blockwrapper">
    <div class="block">Movable</div>
  </div>
</div>




I would say the first step to make this vanilla js is to change var myElement = $("#p1"); to const myElement = document.querySelector('#p1');. It's a bit unclear how the snippet's HTML corresponds to the animation.

You probably want to create a vector from the center of the object to the mouse, and either get the xyz rotation angles of the vector and use those (might work out of the box) or build a lookAt function

Do a bounding box calculation and divide the width, height by 2 - use it to calculate the positions for the x, y?

https://gijsroge.github.io/tilt.js/

how to create something like this without adding any modules etc.. pure js way

How about calculating the distance between the center of the block and the cursor position?
Also, if you want to use jQuery, use the $.fn.on method to attach the listeners.


let sensitivity = 0.5;

function setTranslate($el, x, y, z=0) {
  $el.css({
    transform: `rotateX(${x}deg) rotateY(${y}deg) rotateZ(${z}deg)`
  });
}

$('.blockwrapper').on({
  mousemove: function(event) {
    const $block = $(event.currentTarget).find('.block');
    const $spotlight = $block.find('.spotlight');
  
    let { clientX: x, clientY: y } = event;
    let rect = $block[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    // Calculate the center of the element
    let centerX = rect.left + rect.width / 2;
    let centerY = rect.top + rect.height / 2;

    // Calculate the relative position from the center
    let deltaX = (x - centerX);
    let deltaY = (y - centerY);

    // Calculate the rotation angles to move away from the cursor
    let rotateX = -deltaY * sensitivity; // Invert to tilt away
    let rotateY = deltaX * sensitivity;  // Invert to tilt away

    setTranslate($block, rotateX, rotateY);

    // Move the spotlight
    let spotlightSize = $spotlight.width();
    let spotlightX = x - rect.left - spotlightSize / 2;
    let spotlightY = y - rect.top - spotlightSize / 2;

    $spotlight.css({
      transform: `translate(${spotlightX}px, ${spotlightY}px)`,
      opacity: 1
    });
  },
  mouseleave: function(event) {
    const $block = $(event.currentTarget).find('.block');
    const $spotlight = $block.find('.spotlight');
  
    setTranslate($block, 0, 0);

    // Hide the spotlight
    $spotlight.css({ opacity: 0 });
  }
});
body {
  background: #000;
}

.container {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.blockwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background: red;
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  will-change: transform;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: thin solid #444;
  border-radius: 1.8rem;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #eee;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.spotlight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgb(255,255,0);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,0,0.5) 0%, rgba(255,255,0,0.1) 25%, transparent 75%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="blockwrapper">
    <div class="block">
      Movable #1
      <div class="spotlight"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blockwrapper">
    <div class="block">
      Movable #2
      <div class="spotlight"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blockwrapper">
    <div class="block">
      Movable #3
      <div class="spotlight"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




This is good - how would we improve it with easing so it doesn't snap back so fast. Reduce the effect power so we can only tilt the tiles a little and it reverts back to neutral slower instead of snapping back.

I got the spotlight affect to have these qualities - - .light-outside {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
opacity: .3;
filter: blur(70px);
background-color: #fff;
}

the reference is the experience section here -- https://az-black.webflow.io/#experince

@TheOldCounty the snapping is the sensitivity. You can set it to a lower value like 0.1.

how would we improve it with easing so it doesn't revert back so fast.

@TheOldCounty I added a transition style rule to the .block.

@Mr.Polywhirl, great answer.
